# Remove a round transparent section of an Image c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, transparency, system.drawing

I am creating an Circle on a bitmap but want to have a hole in it. After serching for half an hour I only found ways to crop an image to a circle. The hard thing is, that the hole in the middle should be transparent as the rest of the Image.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avdrv.png) is the base image and [the yellow circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAGC5.png) represents the transparent area that should be added.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Bitmaps do not support transparency.  The images you linked in your question are, fortunately, not bitmaps but rather PNG images which _do_ support transparency.  I recommend you heavily edit your question to replace mentions of "bitmap" with "png" instead.  I took the liberty of replacing the `bitmap` tag with `png` in hopes that it will attract the right expertise :)

Comment: Well ` new Bitmap(2048, 2048, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)` works for me totally fine and is transparent!

Comment: @clark: Do not confuse BMP file format with GDI Bitmapobject!

Comment: @TaW it's too late; I've already done that.

Comment: Okay mb then, so what would you suggest else then?

Comment: I see it but you can always delete a comment as you deleted the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start is simple: Create a transparent bitmap by doing a `g.Clear(Color.Transparent)` and then draw/fill a circle in a color.

The next step is a bit trickier: You next want to paint the hole with transparency.

To do so you need to switch the Graphics object to the right `CompositingMode`; default is `SourceOver` but you want `SourceCopy`. The former **overlays** the alpha values creating mixed colors. The latter will do what we want: Draw the hole by **copying** the drawn colors **including alpha** right over the old ones..

Here is an example:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    //g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.DarkGreen, 100, 100, 300, 300);
    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Transparent, 200, 200, 100, 100);
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

This is what is looks like in a `PictureBox` with a `BackgroundImage`:

[image]

A few notes:

- You can also use a semi-transparent brush to create a 'tinted' hole; do not use anti-aliasing for this though, as it would introduce colored fringes.
- We used simple circles here but with a `GraphicsPath` you can create and fill shapes of almost any shape and complexity..
- And using a `GraphicsPath` would also have been an alternative to filling with transparency: By **first** adding the large and **then** the smaller, inner ellipse the path would have been **created with a hole** and filling it would have had the very same result! But I found the solution above more instructive..
- Final note: As clarkitect noted, to save, do use a format that supports transparency. `Png` is always recommended..

Comment: Thanks alot, never could have thought of something like this!