# Drawing a Transparent Ellipse with System.Drawing on .Net Core turns white

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.drawing, ubuntu-18.04

So I am using `System.Drawing` on my ubuntu 18.04 system. It works just fine but when I try to draw something transperent it is totally white. It works on Windows in VS just fine and everything else is transperent as well like the background.

This is my code:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(2048, 2048))  
{
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        gfx.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        gfx.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        gfx.FillPie(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(37, 107, 125)), 350, 350, 1324, 1324, 270, 180);
        gfx.FillPie(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(244, 175, 55)), 350, 350, 1324, 1324, 450, 180);
        gfx.FillEllipse(Brushes.Transparent, 610, 610, 794, 794);

         ...
    }
}
```

The yellow circle is intendet but not the white thing in the middle, it should be transperent ofc.

Thanks for any kind of help

[image: .]

Comment: I don't do .NET Core. Does it support GraphicsPaths? They are in System.Drawing.Drawing2D in Winforms..

Comment: Well the I can use the namespace System.Drawing.Drawing2D why do you ask? @TaW

Comment: Because of the alternative way of creating a hole using a GrphicsPath. See the last part of my answer!

Comment: Would it be possible to send the link in here? @TaW

Comment: Which link? To you own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244571/remove-a-round-transparent-section-of-an-image-c-sharp)?

Comment: My bad, I didn't see your edit ^^.